# FabricJS ClipTo shape with angle attribute on Image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I'm stuck with a problem, where I have to crop a shape out of an image. Everything works until I'm not giving an angle to the shape.

I'd like to know how am i supposed to modify my test case to fix this issue.

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Xyzor/kdu576bn/)

```
bg.clipTo = function(ctx) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.rotate((angle * -1) * (Math.PI / 180));
    ctx.rect(left, top, width, height);
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.stroke();
  };
```